# Jenkins user login using remote PostgreSQL Database

Tags: database, postgresql, jenkins, remote-access

We have a database name 'user' in local machine and [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) installed in remote machine ([Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/)).

-- We have some username/password in 'user' database.

-- Now, we want to authenticate a Jenkins user by using the 'user' database.

Jenkins uses file system instead of database. Now how can we authenticate a jenkins user using PostgreSQL database that is stored in remote machine ?

> N.B. We already enable jenkins [global security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup). Now when a user
>   does signup, a directory is created with the name of username followed
>   by a config.xml file. Next time when the user wants to login, jenkins
>   read the password from that config.xml file.

We exactly want that when a user wants to login, jenkins will read the password (of corresponding userName) from remote database.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for authentication in Jenkins, not just *"file system instead of database".* See [Standard Security Setup.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup)

You could use the [LDAP Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin) and the [OpenLDAP-POSTGRESQL HOWTO.](http://www.darold.net/projects/ldap_pg/HOWTO/)